# How to choose an English proofreading and editing services for master thesis?

Tags: academic-writing, editing, proofreading

I am a master's student,  and English is not my native language.

To review and edit my thesis in English,  I need an online reliable English proofreading and editing service.

What do you suggest that I look for when choosing a source?  Are there specific issues that a graduate student writer needs that a general fiction writer does not?

- About the time, I have 10 to 15 days, and my topic is computer science, especially medical image processing.

Comment: Hi, SoK!  I edited this some to try to clarify the question and to make it more generalizable.  It may be helpful if YOU edit to also answer a few questions: What is your timeline -- is this an emergency?  What is your major or the topic of this thesis?  What other resources for editing have you tried?  Are the school's tutors not open to proofreading?   More details are often helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does your university have a Writing Center?  They probably have tutors, especially ones focused on ESL issues, and on graduate-school writing.  I recommend going through them first.

Comment: +1 these service centers are often unjustly overlooked

Comment: No, there is no Writing Center in my university, for that I seek another way to edit my thesis english